# Is there any way to get the integrated equation in R?

Tags: r

The integrate() function returns the integrated value, but what if the user wants to take the integrated equation for an interval?

For example, the normal case of integrate() is like below:

```
integrate(f = function(x){2 * x}, lower = 1, upper = 2)

>3 with absolute error < 3.3e-14
```

But I want to write something like this:

```
integrate(f = function(x){2 * x}, lower = t, upper = t + 1)
```

to get

```
2 * t + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe this ? http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/symbolic/

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thank you. It looks to do the right things I want to do. But, the example code in the links doesn't work even the package is successfully installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ryacas package does symbolic computation:

```
install.packages("Ryacas")
library(Ryacas)
help(pac=Ryacas)

yacas("Integrate(x,t,t+1)2*x")
# expression((t + 1)^2 - t^2)

Simplify("%")  # apply simplification to last result
# expression(2 * t + 1)
```